# WordPress. Menu item skipped due to missing menu slug

Tags: wordpress, import, menu, slug

I'm trying to import an XML file with all content via WordPress Importer. The import is successful, everything is in their place,  but I am getting many `Menu item skipped due to missing menu slug` notices.

What could be the cause of this? It seems like slugs didn't export from the main site. Please help.

Comment: could you not just recreate the menu?

Comment: Theme is for client and I want to create default menus via import.